# iOS7: UITableViewCell from one of its subviews

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I have an UITableViewCell with an UIStepper on it. When the stepper value change it triggers a method:

```
-(void) stepperDidStep: (UIStepper*) sender
```

I need to get the UITableViewCell from the sender.

Until iOS7 this code worked fine:

```
-(void) stepperDidStep: (UIStepper*) sender
{
 UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) sender.superview.superview;
 //...
}
```

Now, in iOS7+Autolayout I get this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) sender.superview;
```

cell is **UITableViewCellContentView**

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) sender.superview.superview;
```

cell is **UITableViewCellScrollView** (???)

Question: What is the best way to get the cell from the stepper in iOS7?

Thanks

Nicola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just set the `tag` of the `UIStepper` same as `indexPath.Row` in the `data-source` method `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Then in the `stepperDidStep:` method, get the desired cell using `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` like this:

```
-(void) stepperDidStep: (UIStepper*) sender{

     UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[yourTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I didn't test it, but i'm using similar code to find the viewcontroller of a view

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableCellUnderView:(UIView *)view {
    Class class = [UITableViewCell class];
    // Traverse responder chain. Return first found UITableViewCell
    UIResponder *responder = view;
    while ((responder = [responder nextResponder]))
        if ([responder isKindOfClass:class])
            return (UITableViewCell *)responder;

    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't get the cell by checking the superview. It's too unreliable. The cell has some hidden views which complicates things even further.

Instead, subclass UIStepper and give it a custom property of UITableViewCell (possibly a weak reference) then set it to the cell when setting up the UIStepper, and then grab the cell when your stepperDidStep: method is called.

Something like:

```
@interface CellStepper : UIStepper
@property (nonatomic, weak) UITableViewCell* cell;
@end
```

.

```
-(void) stepperDidStep: (CellStepper*) sender
{
 UITableViewCell *cell = sender.cell;
 //...
}
```